# skip button on splash screen inxcode

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

I have a splash screen that fades out and then the main view fades in.
The splash remains for a period of five seconds.
How can i skip this with a skip button  with the same dynamic of fading out and then fading in to the main view.

Comment: The splash page intro is an integral part of the app as well as giving it some loading time but i was wishing to have an option to skip and go to main viewcontroller. Its more a spring bored for main experience that the app offers. in most cases i can see that it would be relevant disband with some needless showy splash screen but this is a unique  scenario ..thanks for your imput though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jim is correct although if you still want a skip button on your splash screen, you could create a new view controller and view and call it `rootViewController` and in the App Delegate specify that the app should open to rootViewController. In rootViewController, you can have a UIImageView with the splash screen image and a "skip" UIButton that transitions to the main view immediately. Hope this helps.

Comment: @johnathanbridges Remember to up vote and mark as answer if I helped!

Comment: @quegal i created a rootViewcontroler with UIImageView and UIButton and it removes it self from superview but it also removes the UIImage from the main view.

Comment: @johnathanbridges Could you elaborate further? I'm not quite sure I understand.

Comment: first thing first... cant seem to find out how you vote...iv been ading feed back in the form of yes for this is helpfull..

Comment: @Quegalit seems ineed to biuld up a reputation of 15 im only at 1 which is very limiting as i set up an account with image shack to upload images of code ill vot up when i acquire more reputation points

Comment: @johnathanbridges theres some reputation.

Comment: I can't be online all the time since I'm on a cruise and the wifi is expensive, but I'll try to help whenever I can.

Answer (score 3):

If you can skip it, don't put it in in the first place.

Launch images are **not** designed for splash screens.  They are there to give the illusion of faster loading applications.  Apple's Human Interface Guidelines specifically tell you not to do this:

> [**Avoid displaying an About window or a splash screen.** In general, try to avoid providing any type of startup experience that prevents people from using your application immediately.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW25)
>
> [Avoid using your launch image as an opportunity to provide:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5)
>
> - An “application entry experience,” such as a splash screen
> - An About window
> - Branding elements, unless they are a static part of your application’s first screen
>
> Because users are likely to switch among applications frequently, you should make every effort to cut launch time to a minimum, and you should design a launch image that downplays the experience rather than drawing attention to it.

You are specifically required to follow the HIG by the App Store review guidelines and your application may be rejected for breaking any of the rules within it.

Comment: +1 Splash screens in apps are very annoying/pointless/egotistical

Comment: @skinnyTOD thanks for your view I hear you but this is a unique situation